# Install ubuntu server 12.04.2 LTS with RAID 5

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, raid5

I'm currently installing Ubuntu server 12.04.2.
The hardware is as follows :
1 500Gb HDD for Ubuntu
4 3Tb HDD's for the raid 5 array.

I'm just wondering : during the partition part of the install, do I simply install the OS on the 500Gb HDD, partitionning only this one and leaving the other HDD's for the moment. Or can I set the raid up at the same time ?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to use the RAID for general storage not directly tied to your Ubuntu install - i.e. not using it for /home, /var or other directories - I would set up the RAID after installing onto the 500GB drive. You would still have the option later on for moving those directories to partitions created on the RAID.

Comment: I do intend to use the raid HDD's for storage. Is the option to set the raid up in the partition part of the install not a good idea to use ? I'm a beginner in linux based OS's and I'm wondering what would be the easiest AND safest way to prep that server...

Comment: I'm not sure what RAID options are presented during install (I have a hardware RAID that's configured through BIOS) but most likely if the option is there it will be using mdadm to configure the RAID. You could try setting up the RAID during install and trash and reconfigure it if it doesn't work the way you want. Your OS will be safe on the 500GB drive and you can tinker with the RAID without fear of hosing your system.

Comment: Cool then I'll go on with the install's raid configuration. I'll update my post about what'll happen, good or bad. Thanks to you for the quick answers !